# class File_pointer - is this good c++?

Tags: c++, file-pointer

My c++ program uses many file pointers and has many return statements.
To avoid reaching a return statement without closing all open file pointers, i wrote this class, based upon the assumption that I am guaranteed that all objects' destructors are automatically called, when reaching a return statement.
Is my assumption true?
And is it good code?

*Constructor and destructor in File_pointer.cpp*

```
File_pointer::File_pointer(string filename)
{
    fptr.open(filename.c_str());
};

File_pointer::~File_pointer()
{
    fptr.close();
};
```

*Example of implementation*

```
int main ()
{
    File_pointer myfile("myfile.txt");
    int x = 2;
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:     return x;
        case 2:     return x;
        default:
            break;
    };

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the type of `fptr`? For C-style FILE pointers you can [use `unique_ptr`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4679), so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. For C++ iostreams, you don't even have to do *anything*.

Comment: It is worth to see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB-bdWKwXsU), especially from 0:27:30, part **Resources and Errors**. It answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Video is bookmarked... @KerrekSB I thought that before exiting programs, I should always call close() for any pointer capable of writing to a file, or nasty things would happen. Is this true at all then, or am i just wasting my time ensuring this?

Comment: It's entirely possible you're just wasting time, yes. It's best to start with the documentation of whatever library you're using and make sure you know what everything is doing rather than acting on guesswork and hearsay.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this true?

Yes; all objects with [*automatic* storage duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) have their destructors called when they go out of scope.

To clarify, an *automatic* object is a non-static local object that wasn't dynamically allocated.

> And is it good code?

That's subjective.  But what I will say is that relying on scoping to automatically invoke destructors is a very common C++ idiom, known by the bizarre name of [*resource acquisition is initialisation (RAII)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

Classes like `std::ofstream` already use RAII; their destructor automatically closes the file.  So if your `fptr` is a `std::ofstream`, for instance, then your wrapper class is entirely superfluous.

Comment: There are no "dynamic variables" in C++. All variables are either local or static. Only *objects* can be dynamic. (Therefore, for example, you cannot have a "dynamic reference": references are never objects.)

Answer (score 0):

RAII, sure.

Or use boost smart pointers if you can to [wrap resources](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#incomplete). Always better tested than anything you do yourself however simple.

Answer (score 0):

i presume that `fptr` is the `FILE` pointer in your `File_pointer` class

Though your approach is close to what RAII  paradigm, I should point out that you are not handling the errors appropriately.

e.g. what if `fopen` fails ?

Comment: If `fptr` was a `FILE*` you couldn't call `fptr.open("")`